# Is it possible to use Ant Design straight into the browser in combination with Reactjs without Webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, antd

I have very specific scenario where I have create-react-app configured React Single Page Application(SPA) within the ASP.NET Core framework. Along with the SPA I have some static Razor pages on the server taking care of some stuff such as authentication and profile management. I have already tried Ant Design with my SPA and it works fine. Now I would like to unify the layout of my SPA with my static pages by using Ant Design directly on the browser in my static Razor pages in combination with Reactjs.

I know that using reactjs in the browser is possible as described here https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

In the Ant Design documentation in the section **Import in Browser** is briefly mentioned that it is possible to use the `antd` js library straight into the browser as a global variable although not recommended https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce, but I am wondering whether there is some working example which illustrates how it's done exactly.

Here I've created a minimal example with help of the information from the mentioned links above:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>React and Ant Design browser example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/antd@3.23.1/dist/antd.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="like_button_container"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/antd@3.23.1/dist/antd.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        'use strict';
        const e = React.createElement;
        class LikeButton extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = { liked: false };
            }

            render() {
                if (this.state.liked) {
                    return 'You liked this.';
                }

                return e(
                  'button',
                  { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },
                  'Like'
                );
            }
        }

        let domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
        ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

By opening the example above in the browser I get the following error:

```
Panel.js:272 Uncaught TypeError: ef(...) is not a function
    at Module.i.m.a (Panel.js:272)
    at i (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.i.m.a (index.js:25)
    at i (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.i.m.a (antd.min.js:50)
    at i (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at universalModuleDefinition:9
    at universalModuleDefinition:1
```

And also now I still have to use the 'antd' components into the example, but I don't know how to reference to them. If I do the following where `Button` should be a globally assigned antd button component it complains '**ReferenceError: Button is not defined**':

```js
return e(
  Button,
  { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },
  'Like'
 );
```

I would appreciate some suggestions how to make that example running.

Answer (score 2):

This thread is the first stack overflow question when searching "ant design react without webpack".

Here an example with React, ant design and babel (for jsx):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>React and Ant Design browser example</title>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/antd@4.16.13/dist/antd.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/antd@4.16.13/dist/antd.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
        const App = () => {
            const [liked, setLiked] = React.useState(false);
            if (liked) return <p>You liked this</p>
            return <antd.Button type="primary" onClick={() => setLiked(true)}>Primary Button</antd.Button>
        };
    </script>
    <script type="text/babel">
        ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root')); 
    </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think add the  type=module property inside <script> will be better

Answer (score -2):

Here are docs about how to use React and antd in browser without webpack.

https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce#Import-in-Browser
https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Comment: Thank you! I tried to make a working example with the help of the mentioned links but without any success so far. I have updated my question. I would appreciate a lot any help and suggestion to make the example working.